# JMeter Screenshotting

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, jmeter

I am able to get a screenshot in my JMeter test scripts using the Selenium chrome web driver. This works, but now I want to get screenshots following an authentication request. Is there a way to capture the screen as displayed in the HTTP request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is, theoretically you could try libraries like [this one](https://github.com/hkirk/java-html2image) or [this one](https://docs.aspose.com/html/java/converting-between-formats/html-to-image-conversion/) from [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) using [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy), but I don't think you will get what you want

The main reason is given at [JMeter project main page](https://jmeter.apache.org/):

> **JMeter is not a browser**, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. In particular, J**Meter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages**. Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

[HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler downloads only HTML, you won't get any images, scripts, styles, fonts, etc. so even if you try to use the aforementioned libraries you will get a "screenshot" which doesn't have anything in common with how does the page look in reality.